# Post Method HTTP response is 200 but no data changed In web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to post data form my code but no data changed . when I debug the code it got me 200 which mean code is good . I tried to test in fiddler and data is changed successfully . I want to know where is the wrong ?
this is my service including url

```
 public static async Task<string> PostOrderAsync(MachinePostModel Order)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Order);
                var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://94.205.253.150:2016/api/JobOrder", content);

                return data;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

and this is the step where i send order object

```
 private async Task<bool> AcceptPostOrder()
        {
            MachinePostModel OrderDetails = new MachinePostModel();
                try
                {

                OrderDetails.ID = 1163;
                OrderDetails.joStatus = "should to wait";
                OrderDetails.remarks = "hello remarks";

                var Client = await Services.MachineTestPostService.PostOrderAsync(OrderDetails);
                    return true;

                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                await MachineTestOrderView.machineobj.DisplayAlert("Alert", exc.Message, "OK");
                return false;
            }

        }
```

finally my model

```
   public class MachinePostModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        public string joStatus { get; set; } 

    }
```

Get link to check if data is changed

```
http://94.205.253.150:2016/api/JobOrder/Get?regId=1&driverID=35&status=All%20Status
```

Comment: I Think Something is wrong in your Model Try to test your Model with HTTP POST method

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code. Firstly, decorate your action with `HttpPost` attribute and add a parameter for sent complex object.

```
[HttpPost]
private async Task<bool> AcceptPostOrder(MachinePostModel Order)
{
    MachinePostModel OrderDetails = new MachinePostModel();
    try
    {
        OrderDetails.ID = 1163;
        OrderDetails.joStatus = "should to wait";
        OrderDetails.remarks = "hello remarks";

        var Client = await Services.MachineTestPostService.PostOrderAsync(OrderDetails);
            return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        await MachineTestOrderView.machineobj.DisplayAlert("Alert", exc.Message, "OK");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And, there is no routing definition as `api/JobOrder`, so I assume that you are trying to post the data `AcceptPostOrder` method. Change the request endpoint;

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://94.205.253.150:2016/api/AcceptPostOrder", content);
```

Comment: I Did the same steps in fiddler and it worked so the url is right . you can test it . also i can't write [httppost] because it's mobile app not api